# How to redirect after direct upload using youtube api

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api

I am trying to do direct upload of video from server to youtube using youtube api for PHP. The code for upload is in the controller as below
function uploadVideo() {
        require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';

```
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
    //client login
    $authenticationURL = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
    $httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($username = 'myusername@gmail.com', $password = 'password', $service = 'youtube', $client = null, $source = 'videotest',$loginToken = null, $loginCaptcha = null, $authenticationURL);
    $developerKey = 'my-key';
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, "videotest",null,$developerKey);

    $myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

    // create a new Zend_Gdata_App_MediaFileSource object
     $path = Configure::read('Files.write');
     $video = $path . DS . 'videos' . DS .'car.mp4';
    $filesource = $yt -> newMediaFileSource($video);
    $filesource -> setContentType('video/mp4');

    $filesource -> setSlug($video);

    // add the filesource to the video entry
    $myVideoEntry -> setMediaSource($filesource);

    $myVideoEntry -> setVideoTitle('car');
    $myVideoEntry -> setVideoDescription('car video');
    // The category must be a valid YouTube category!
    $myVideoEntry -> setVideoCategory('Autos');


    $myVideoEntry -> SetVideoTags('cars, test');

    $myVideoEntry -> setVideoDeveloperTags(array('mydevtag', 'anotherdevtag'));

    $myVideoEntry->setVideoPrivate();

    // upload URI for the currently authenticated user
    $uploadUrl = "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";


    try {
        $newEntry = $yt -> insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
echo "returned from youtube";
$this -> redirect('/videos/view');

    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
        //print_r($httpException);
        echo $httpException -> getRawResponseBody();
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        print_r($e);
        echo $e -> getMessage();
    }

}
```

The video gets uploaded to my youtube channel, but it after the upload i just see a blank screen and it doesnt get redirected .In fact it does not execute any statement after insertentry. Is there anything am missing here?

Comment: There is a space missing after the $nextUrl in the form, just before the method="post"

Comment: Okay i edited it now to $form = "<form action='?nexturl=". $nextUrl ."' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>";..but still the same blank page and no redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I drilled down on the problem and found that the issue is in the method insertentry in zend/gdata/app.php . For some reason

```
 $returnEntry = new $className($response->getBody());
```

is failing, even though `$response->getBody()` is non-empty. So for now, I commented out the code after post() ,and return null from this method. It works fine and the control comes back to my application. I am not sure if this a bug or am missing on something.It would be great if someone can point out what is going on wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [browser-based upload flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Browser_based_Upload) if you want to submit a video via a HTML form and then automatically redirect to another page after that's complete.

If you insist on using the direct upload flow, then I'm not sure what the answer to your question is, as it's not something directly related to the YouTube API. It just boils down to "how do i redirect to a new web page after making some arbitrary PHP calls".

Comment: I am doing a direct upload inside my cakephp controller. Once my upload is successful, I just see a blank screen(i.e) 
   $this -> redirect('/videos/view'); doesn't redirect.

Comment: $yt->insertEntry, does not return back. But the video is uploaded and no exception is thrown..I have been having a hard time debugging this. Please help!

Comment: I don't know what CakePHP is or why that would preclude you from doing a browser-based upload instead of a direct upload.

Comment: I dont want to upload the video to youtube as soon as the user uploads it to my site. I want the video to be uploaded later (after it is approved by admin). So browser upload will not work for me.